# windows automatic copy / move / delete files

Tags: windows

Is there any utility / software which could periodically / scheduled copy / move / delete files over network or with hard drives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will allow you to setup very complex (or very basic) schedules to run scripts.

[robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) is a great tool which can do all sorts of file minipulations, it works well with UNC paths, `copy` and `xcopy` both require `pushd` and `popd` to map your shares to the Z:\ drive (typically not a problem, and xcopy may even do this automatically) but I find the flexibility and power of `robocopy` to be more useful. It is on Windows Vista / Server 2008 + by default, and a free download from microsoft for XP and Server 2003.

You can use [powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419) or windows command shell to call [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx) and make your copy / move / delete operations.

For example, save the following to a file called `backup.bat` :

```
robocopy \\server1\shareA\ \\server2\backups\shareA\ /MIR
```

This will copy everything on `server1` that is in `shareA` to the backups share on `server2` the `/MIR` switch says to mirror the changes, so deletes in `shareA` are also deleted in `backups\shareA`

Then, open the Task Scheduler, and configure it to run `backup.bat` file every night (or whatever schedule you need to make these copy / move / delete.

Comment: is there not any gui utility like fling

Comment: RichCopy GUI is great tool according to its features. I'll try and update.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a batch file. Use `xcopy` and put it in your Scheduled Tasks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an app that does what you are looking for with a GUI type interface and no scripting/batch files, I used to use a program called Watch Directory. It was very good at doing simple file and folder monitoring and moving by specific rules. 
http://www.watchdirectory.net/
It's not a free app but your question does not mention that the app needs to be free. Nate's answer would be a good route for a DIY free solution.